# In a large component in React I want to click on one element and scroll to another element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

In React I want to click on one element and have the page scroll to another element.
I have seen this question answered on Stack Overflow but I don't know how to implement it inside a large component like the one I am working with.

The operative pieces are buried in the component below, but they are as follows.
Function that should scroll to the element...
`const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current)`

Creation of Ref in the constructor...
`this.myRef = React.createRef()`

The element I want to click on that will scroll to the element desired...
`<a onClick={executeScroll}>`

The element I wish to scroll to...
`<MyForm ref={this.myRef} />`

If I change...
`const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current)`
to
`const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, 1400)`
I get where I want, but of course this doesn't know what element I'm scrolling to and will not work for mobile.

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import Headroom from 'react-headroom'
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import HoverComp from './Hover'
import "animate.css/animate.min.css";
import ScrollAnimation from 'react-animate-on-scroll';
import MyForm from './myform'

import back from '../videos/tokyo_background.mp4'
import white from '../photos/white.jpg'
import fb_icon from '../photos/f.png'
import facebook_logo_white from '../photos/facebook-logo-white-c.png'
import z4881239_28446 from '../photos/84881239_2844929345568110_3163761343.png'


const scrollToRef = (ref) => window.scrollTo(0, this.myRef.current)   

export default class main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
    this.displayName = 'Item';
    this.state = {
      apiResponse: [],
      page: 0,
      isHovered: {}
    }
  }

componentDidMount() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 70);
  this.callAPI();
}

handleMouseEnter = index => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: true } };
  });
};

handleMouseLeave = index => {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: false } };
  });
};

callAPI() {
    fetch('/api/getList')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }))
}

loadMoreRows = () => {
  this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
}

  render() {
    const { apiResponse, page, isHovered } = this.state;

    const executeScroll = () => scrollToRef(this.myRef)

    if(!apiResponse) {
        return <p className="row">Loading</p>
    }
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <Headroom>
        <div className="header-container">
          <div className="header-background">
            <a href="/">
            <h2 className="house-icon">Home</h2>
            </a>
            <a onClick={executeScroll}>
              <h2 className="contact-text">Contact</h2>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Headroom>

      <video autoPlay muted loop className="myVideo" src={back} type="video/mp4" />


        <div class="grid">
        <figure class="effect-romeo">
          <img src={white} alt="img05"/>
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Web <br/> <span>Design</span></h2>
            <p>We build websites large and small with the latest and greatest tools available</p>
          </figcaption> 
        </figure>
        <figure class="effect-romeo">
        <img src={white} alt="img05"/>
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Search <span>Optimization</span></h2>
            <p>We do everything possible to make you the number one search result</p>
          </figcaption> 
          </figure>
          <figure class="effect-romeo">
          <img src={white} alt="img05"/>
          <figcaption>
            <h2>Facebook <span>Integration</span></h2>
            <p>From Facebook Advertizing to creating and managing social media content</p>
          </figcaption> 
          </figure>
      </div>              

      <div className="image-grid">

        <div className='row'>
        <ScrollAnimation animateIn='bounceInRight' animateOnce={true}>
          <img className="house-icon" src={z4881239_28446}/>
            <div className='burb-box'>
              <p className='about-me-header'>About me</p>
              <p className='about-me'>
              </p>
            </div>
          </ScrollAnimation>
          <div className='contact-section'>
            <ScrollAnimation animateIn='bounceInLeft' animateOnce={true}>
              <MyForm ref={this.myRef} />
            </ScrollAnimation>
          </div>
          <div className="spacer"/>
          <img className="facebook-icon" src={fb_icon}/>
          </div>
          <ScrollAnimation animateIn='fadeIn' animateOnce={true}>

            <InfiniteScroll
              className='div-34x'
              dataLength={apiResponse.length}
              next={this.loadMoreRows}
              hasMore={true}
              >
              {Object.values(apiResponse.slice(0, (page+1)*6)).map((value, index) => 
              <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={value.post}>
                <Child
                  onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(index)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseLeave(index)}
                  isHovering={isHovered[index]}
                  src={value.image}
                  comment={value.comment}
                />
              </a>)}
            </InfiniteScroll>
            </ScrollAnimation>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
function Child({ onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, src, comment, isHovering }) {
  return (
      <div className="imagex" onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
        <HoverComp itemTitle={''} photoItemsProp={[src]}/>
        <div className="centered">
        {isHovering && comment}
        {isHovering && <img className='fb-image-icon' src={facebook_logo_white}/>}
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution

You can achieve this without using **refs**.

First, update your `scrollToRef` function:

```
const scrollToElement = (target) => window.scrollTo(0, target.offsetTop);
```

Lastly, update your `executeScroll` function:

```
const executeScroll = (element) => scrollToElement(element.target)
```

#### Notes:

- You are giving the myRef value to form, `<MyForm ref={this.myRef} />`. So when you execute `scrollToRef(this.myRef)`, your code will scroll to that Form.
- to continue using refs, you would need to create a ref for each element you would want to scroll to. For example: `this.contactRef = React.createRef(); this.homeRef = React.createRef(); etc ...`
- then attach these refs to their appropriate elements: `<a id="contact-link" ref={this.contactRef}>`
- then update your executeScroll function to accept the element's ref `const executeScroll = (ref) => {scrollToRef(ref)}`
- lastly, call your onclick function like so: `onClick={() => executeScroll(this.contactRef)}`
- head over to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component) to learn more about ref and the dom.
- `console.log()` stuff to get a visual of the data being thrown around if you're feeling lazy about combing through documentation.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-zud4x) that demonstrates how to achieve the scrollTo using refs and without.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was working for a second but then it just started scrolling to the top of the page, or things like `property 'offsetTop' of undefined` I want to understand. Should I be using refs? You say I don't need to? I couldn't make sense of refs in those docs because my problem is not similar. Can't see the parallels. Sorry for being whiney.

Comment: I might be mixed up between `scrollToElement`and `scrollToRef` or something. I'm pretty much in the dark about what this chain of consts and the ref is doing here.

Comment: Does something need a `this.bind(this)` somewhere?

Comment: That undefined error probably stems from an error with passing the wrong variable. Ensure all your variables are appropriately named. Doing things the react way takes big pp. Patience and Practice. when I get stuck doing something in react, I take a step back from my project and mess around in a new sample app. Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-zud4x) I created that demonstrates both solutions. I included comments and console.logs for you to follow along. I will update my answer to include the link.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This problem is really getting to me because I like to learn, but there isn't a rational reason for it not working. Just now I've been moving the `onClick` to different elements and sometimes the scroll jumps to the desired element. Most of the time it scrolls to the very top. There are no errors. I try it on other browsers and it's the same. React must not know where my desired ref is most of the time.

Comment: Wait, it's just scrolling to the element I am clicking, I think.

Comment: I see, your "you can achieve this without using refs" section was about scrolling to what you're clicking. I'm using the other parts of your answer again and it still always scrolls to the top. Console logging the `ref` displays the object I want to scroll to. Do I dig into the property of the object that has the page's Y location? onClick is `onClick={() => executeScroll(this.contactRef)}` and executeScroll is `    const executeScroll = (ref) => {browserScroll(ref)}`. There must be some kind of feature of React I don't know about here.

Comment: Console logging the `target` in the `browserScroll` function displays the object I want to scroll to. Again, I appreciate you are the only one getting me closer to what's happening here.

Comment: My issue here, and in all the days trying to get this to work center around `  window.scrollTo();` never working with anything except numbers. I have never ever gotten this to translate where anything is.

Comment: SOLVED. Venting about this to you helped me work it out. `window.scrollTo` needed target to be `0, target.current.y`, which if you dig into the ref object IS the Y location. If you want to put that in your answer I'll give you the green check. The lower parts of your answer about clicking on one element to get to another was what I needed and what I used.

Comment: Oh, God. Not all the elements have a `y` attribute.

Comment: The [docs for Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) shows what the function can accept. The property `offsetTop` of an element returns a number. Doing things the react way means breaking up components into isolated parts as you saw in the sandbox's RefExample. I suggested the answer without refs so you can get what you want without re-writing much code. My advice would be to rebuild your component without copy-pasta and select one solution for your scroll-to-element. Follow the example of your choice in the sandbox in your rebuild.

Comment: If you are passing a **ref** to the **scrollToElement** function, then `window.scrollTo(0, target.current.offsetTop)` should work for you.

Comment: "My advice would be to rebuild your component without copy-pasta" I'm good. I understand it now. Everything that's happening. The only thing that really took me the past 24 hours to dig into was adding `current` to the middle of `target.current.offsetTop` instead of `target.offsetTop` because of whatever reason no answer on the internet had that solution. In the process I did learn everything in your answer, which started as copypasta. Though maybe bacause of some bad practices(?) `offsetTop` does not return the true y of the element displayed and something like +200 doesn't yield results.